# Using scapy with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy, packet-sniffers, packets

I am trying to do a graphical representation of packets using scapy,python-2.7 and some graph module (which i haven't thought of yet). Basically, I want to read the types of data packets from a pcap file using scapy, parse it and in turn simulate a graph.

I have written the following code to just check how rdpcap works:

```
**from scapy.utils import rdpcap
packets = rdpcap("/Packet_Inspection/Sample_2.pcap000")
print packets**
```

And i keep getting the following error:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
 >> File "test1.py", line 8, in <module>
    packets = rdpcap("/Packet_Inspection/Sample_2.pcap000")
 >>File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\utils.py", line 559, in rdpcap
    return fdesc.read_all(count=count)
  >>File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\utils.py", line 729, in read_all
    res = RawPcapReader.read_all(self, count)
  >>File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\utils.py", line 680, in read_all
    p = self.read_packet()
  >>File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\utils.py", line 725, in read_packet
    p = conf.raw_layer(s)
>>TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable**
```

Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

multiple things could be going wrong here.

does `/Packet_Inspection/Sample_2.pcap000` really exist at the root?

are there packets in the pcap?

also, `rdpcap` returns a python array of scapy `Packet` objects. you could try printing a single instance with `print packets[0]`

Comment: 1. does /Packet_Inspection/Sample_2.pcap000 really exist at the root?
      Yes. I have placed in the same folder as the python.

2. Pcap does contain packets. I checked in Wireshark before putting it up.

3. I tried packets[0] as well and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @crappidy `rdpcap` returns an array of packets, so `packets[0]` return the first element on the array, which is of type `Packet`. `packet[0][0]` returns the first layer of the first packet in the array

Comment: @crappidy no problem. i don't want to admit how long it took me to figure that out